# jQuery .bind(scroll) function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

So the other day, I asked a question on Stackoverflow and got answers. But apparently after struggling with all this time, I am unable to find the resolution. The code that I have works in Chrome and Safari, but does not work in Firefox and IE.

Can anyone tell what is wrong this code?

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($('body').scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $('#cooler-nav').offset().top){   
        $.colorbox({width:"700px", inline:true, href:"#subscribepop"});
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        }

});
```

Basically the goal is to get this colorbox to launch once the user views the div #cooler-nav...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll event doesn't propagate up the DOM tree.  Try binding on the 'body' scroll, not the windows scroll and see if that fixes it for you.

**Edit:**  I went back and checked my code where I've had to do this in the past, and realized I got it backwards. When I've done it in the past, I've used `$(window).scrollTop()` not body.  So, that'd make your code look like:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $('#cooler-nav').offset().top){   
    $.colorbox({width:"700px", inline:true, href:"#subscribepop"});
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
  }
});
```

Comment: Updated answer based upon what I've done in the past for this issue.

Comment: Had this problem now in the end of 2014 and this is still the solution. Firefox had fixed this and I only needed this to fix this problem in IE

Answer (score 0):

You should change your if-clause to check for scrollTop on 'body,html' to make it work in FF

Comment: Doing this makes it work in Firefox but it stops working in Chrome, and Safari. Doesn't work in IE at all.

Comment: Please double check if you used 'body,html' or 'body','html' . While the former should work in both, the latter should produce the behaviour you describe

Comment: Just double checked. 'body,html'<< it works in Firefox but not in Chrome etc.

Using 'body','html' makes it work in Chrome but not in Firefox.